# How do you achieve acceptable performance metrics for your web application?

Tags: performance

What analysis do you currently perform to achieve performance metrics that are acceptable? Metrics such as page weight, response time, etc. What are the acceptable metrics that are  currently recommended?

Answer (score 1):

This is performance related, so 'it depends' :)

Do you have existing metrics (an existing application) to compare against? Do you have users that are complaining - can you figure out why?

The other major factor will depend on what network sits between the application and the users. On a LAN, page weight probably doesn't matter. On a very slow WAN, page size (esp WRT to TCP windowing) is going to dwarf the impact of server time.

As far as analysis:

1. Server response time, measured by a load test tool on the same network as the app
2. Client response time, as measured by a browser / client either on a real or simulated network

The workload for 1) follows the 80/20 rule in terms of transaction mix. For 2), I look at some subset of pages for a browser app and run empty cache and full cache cases to simulate new vs returning users.

Answer (score 1):

Use webpagetest.org  to get waterfall charts.
Do RUM, Real User Monitoring, using Google Analytics snippet with Site Speed Javascript enabled.
They are the bare minimum to do.